# What is the best way to measure android app screen rendering time

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I would like to measure how long (in millis) it took to fully render a screen in android . I am trying to use System.nanoTime() to measure the time . But where will I start the timer and end the timer to make sure the screen is fully loaded or rendered . Tried in onCreate and onResume , but its not giving consistent results

Comment: Since the actual rendering happens on another thread in any modern version of android, this isn't going to work.

Comment: @GabeSechanEven if the rendering happens at another background thread , the control goes back the the actual activity which intiated the rendering right ?

Comment: The best question here is what are you actually trying to measure?  How long it takes from onCreate() to seeing the screen?  That won't be dominated by render time, it will be dominated by layout/measure time (which is distinct from render time) and what your app is doing at startup.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for looking in to my question . I am trying to measure how long it take to load(render/paint) the screen fully starting from when onCreate() in invoked on the activity. Just looking for some help on how to indentify whether the screen is fully rendered programatically.  eg: if I click the alarm in the clock app, how long it takes to load the alarm screen fully. Thanks

Comment: SO because the actual rendering is asynchronous to the actual main UI thread and doesn't cause a callback, that's actually very hard to measure.  I'd think the best proxy would be to call setGlobalLayoutListener on your root view, and put the end timer in that listener's onGlobalLayout.  That will include the layout/measure time, but not the actual drawing-  which should be minor compared to the layout.

Comment: If you are still using Android Studio version lower than 3.1. than you can user Android Device Monitor to get render informations about your layout. In 3.2. Android Device Monitor is deprecated and that should be possible inside Profiler.